# Problem loading JS files in django project

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django

I am currently working on a project which uses templet inheritance. and from other tamplet when i am trying to load two different javascript files having 2 windows.onload function it load only one which is on the top.

*i am attaching a image which show both the directory structure and code*

[image with code and dir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHfdh.png)

I am expecting that my all windows.onload fun run from diff JS files at once when document is loaded.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i already added the image. showing the linking of 2 javascript files both having windows.onload function